# unresolved reference to class, methods

Tags: kotlin

I am new to `kotlin` (basically started today)

I want to write a `dsl` like builder for my `GRLMessage` class.

```
data class GRLMessage(var method: GRLMethod, var headers: Map<String, String>, var multipart: Object) {

    fun message(init: GRLMessage.() -> Unit) : GRLMessage {
        init()
        return this
    }

    fun method(init: GRLMessage.() -> GRLMethod) : GRLMessage {
        method = init()
        return this
    }

    fun headers(init: GRLMessage.() -> Unit) : GRLMessage {
        init()
        return this
    }

    fun header(init: GRLMessage.() -> Pair<String, String>) : GRLMessage {
        headers.plus(init())
        return this
    }

    fun multipart(init: GRLMessage.() -> Object) : GRLMessage {
        multipart = this.init()
        return this
    }
}
```

In order to check it I added test.

```
import org.junit.Assert.*
import org.junit.*

class GRLMessageTest {

    data class DummyMultipart(val field: String) {}

    @Test fun grlMessageBuilderTest() {
        val grlMessage = GrlMessage().message {
            method { GRLMethod.POST }
            headers {
                header { Pair("contentType", "object") }
                header { Pair("objectType", "DummyMultipart") }
            }
            multipart { DummyMultipart("dummy") }
        }

        val multipart = DummyMultipart("dummy")
        val headers = mapOf(
                Pair("contentType", "object"),
                Pair("objectType", "DummyMultipart")
        )
        val method = GRLMethod.POST

        assertEquals(multipart, grlMessage.multipart)
        assertEquals(headers, grlMessage.headers)
        assertEquals(method, grlMessage.method)
    }
}
```

Both classes are in the same packages (relatively - one is in `src/main/kotlin`, another one is in `src/test/kotlin`).

When I try to build application using `gradle build` it fails on `compileTestKotlin` task with errors

```
GRLMessageTest.kt: (13, 26): Unresolved reference: GrlMessage
GRLMessageTest.kt: (14, 13): Unresolved reference: method
GRLMessageTest.kt: (15, 13): Unresolved reference: headers
GRLMessageTest.kt: (17, 17): Unresolved reference: header
GRLMessageTest.kt: (19, 13): Unresolved reference: multipart
```

What is the problem?

Here is the layout

[image]

Here is the `build.gradle` for that concrete subproject and plugin

[image]
[image]

Comment: can you show your `build.gradle` and also if you are in a package or not for each of these files (what is the `package` statement of each file)

Comment: also what version of Kotlin?

Comment: Writing a DSL in Kotlin is not the simplest first day task, I'd recommend you have a full understanding of the language and have studied other Kotlin based DSL implementations first, there are a lot of tricks to know and your approach will have problems due to fighting the data class and that default constructor and more.  I'd start simpler and come back to DSL after you have the breadth of the language under your belt.

Comment: Well I prefer learning language by using it for my selected purpose. Also I am not planning to dive deep into Kotlin (at least now) as I mostly Java and Groovy. Just wanted to try it in scope of my application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a naming mismatch between your class and the reference to the class from your tests.

Your class is named `GRLMessage` but in your test you reference it as `GrlMessage` and Kotlin is case sensitive.  These are therefore not considered the same.  You need to use exactly the same identifier in both.

Comment: Oh I see! Thanks. Now I get other errors (regarding type mismatch and no value passing) but whatever. I think I know how to resolve it.

Comment: new questions should be new SO questions after you work to resolve them of course.  Enjoy Kotlin!

Comment: Well I know that.